# 84' wall leans 5",17' out. Pulling to plumb, + columns, save wall?

Tags: concrete-block

84' wall leans 5",17' out. Pulling to plumb, add columns, save wall?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvnVY.jpg)

Comment: It is really hard to tell what the issue is with your description and picture.  Common sense tells me that an exterior wall does not have to be perfectly straight nor should something that long be taken down because of a slight lean.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a privacy wall, leave it be, unless you really want to spend a lot of bucks tearing it down and rebuilding it. If it is a retainer wall, with the dirt a lot higher on one side than the other, which is pushing the wall out, then it may need to be rebuilt if it is a relatively new wall and was not built properly to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The wall looks like there's about 6' difference between the soil on the upper level and the soil on the lower level. If it's 5" out of plumb in that distance, then that's quite a bit. We worry when it's an inch or so, as it's not suppose to move at all...

Yes, a pilaster (a masonry column built against the wall) could support the wall and keep it from continuing to move. It would need to be designed by an architect or structural engineer (not a civil engineer).  However, you need to figure out what's causing the problem.

It could have moved due to 1) the footing settling, 2) moisture accumulating behind the wall, and/or 3) an additional load was placed near the wall on the upper level.

1) If the footing has settled due to a change in the soil conditions, then the "new" pilaster could be placed on that same soil that is starting to move. The footing for the pilaster will need to be extra large to compensate for the weaker / moving soil.

2) If moisture is accumulating behind the wall, then drains need to be installed to eliminate the moisture.

3) If a new additional load was placed against the wall on the upper level and you know what that "new" additional load was, then you could eliminate it or keep it from happening again with a barrier installed on the upper level and it should prevent the wall from continuing to move.  If you can't do that or if you think the load will return, (like a large truck parking next to the wall, ) then a pilaster could help stop the wall from moving again.

All are extremely expensive. So, I'd recommend you monitor the wall to see if it continues to move. If it doesn't, then it was probably a one time event, like an extra large truck parked next to the wall, rather than a continuing problem like moving soil, water accumulating behind the wall, etc. which will cause the wall to continue to move.

"Monitoring" to me means "carefully" checking it daily for a week or so, then checking it bi-weekly, then monthly. There should be a pattern develop and you'll know if you need to call for some professional help. The longest we ever monitored anything is two years. You, however, may want to do it much longer so you can sleep at night. Also, make a journal and write it down. Make notes about weather, (rain, long periods of drought, etc.), traffic near wall, construction in the neighborhood, power company adding poles near by, etc. (There's a 58 story building in San Francisco right now that is sinking and leaning due to the City extending a subway tunnel.) Note anything unusual.